# How to make partly broadcast in UDP?

Tags: python, networking

I would like to send a message in UDP in broadcast except of `ip=123.123.123.123` is there any way to do so?

how should I modify this code:

```
MYPORT = 8080

import sys, time
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while 1:
    data = 'python is awesome' + '\n'
    s.sendto(data, ('<broadcast>', MYPORT))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: no , you can't exclude one IP from a range. But you could do two broadcast to two different ranges that exclude the one ip.

Comment: @MarcB: You can't even do that. There is no such thing as "broadcasting to a range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a broadcast IP packet, there is only one packet sent from the sender machine. There isn't any way to determine who receives it, because *every* machine on the same network receives it.

Basic IP packet addressing has two choices:

- send to a single IP address
- send to the subnet broadcast address

You may be able to use ["multicasting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) to solve your problem, but that is considerably more complicated.